# Underline not disappearing from link

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting the underline on my link to disappear. Please have a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/DUE39/

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="heim.html">lrle</a></li>
<li><a href="sida1.html">rarw</a></li>
<li><a href="sida2.html">de</a></li>
<li><a href="sida3.html">Nignog </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
width:550px;
height:35px;
font-family:Tahoma,Geneva;
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:3px 2px 3px #333333;
border-radius:8px;
border: dotted black;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li {
display: inline;
padding: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

As you see, I have tried setting the text-decoration to none in every place I can think of.

Any ideas on how to remove the underline?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Comment: I like how this was down-voted just because it was a question easy to resolve. This is probably the third user I'll get shunned for simply being new to programming.

Comment: `.menu a { text-decoration: none; }`?

Comment: The fact it is easy to resolve shows lack of effort from your side. No matter how retarded a community (based on a single downvote wtf) you still need to do your research.

Comment: a-tags does not inherit from their parents, because they have an own specific default value for the text-decoration property.

Comment: The problem may be easy to resolve to the trained eye, but do you expect a newbie to realize how anchors work with id's and classes? I had no idea that the problem was lying there. And the comment (which I erased) about the community was due to all of my users getting shut down because I ask simple questions (again, because I am new).

Comment: Yes I expect people to read the documentation, spec, other resources and this site.

Comment: there is no light when fighting against (community- or rule-)gravity.

Comment: I had read several other similar questions and then realized that the question could be caused by a broad range of things that I didn't even understand.

Comment: In that case I am very sorry to inform you that you are expected to have a minimum understanding of what you are doing on this site.

Comment: @user3078100 A tip for next time you get a similar problem, try using the Chrome developer tools. They will fairly clearly tell you where styles are inherited from if you just choose 'Inspect element' on the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS selector `.menu li a` to target the anchor

```
.menu li a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tGjm5/

Comment: This nullifies my inline for some reason. See my JS fiddle.

Comment: @user3078100 I'm not understanding the issue.  Could you further explain?  I'm advocating for adding a new CSS style, not replacing the old one (except removing `text-decoration`). See: http://jsfiddle.net/DUE39/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
.menu > ul > li > a {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
.menu ul {
   text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Will be applied to the child of ul, but wouldn't be applied to `a` hyperlink. So for that, you need to specify the a tag too as

```
.menu ul a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

This will be applied to the link in the menu!

Have a look at your fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/DUE39/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `.menu li a`, or precise a where you need it